# Why I can't find the 'swift language version' item in my Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10.1

Why can't I find the 'swift language version' item in my Xcode 10.1?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Is the target a CLI (command line interface)? If yes the language version is not displayed (for whatever reasons)

Comment: For CLI, you can't choose the Swift version: it will be the one matching the current Command Lines Tools version:
- 4.2 for Xcode 10.1
- 5.0 for Xcode 10.2
- 5.1 for Xcode 11
- etc.